# Java 8 service calls and functional constructs

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I am trying to learn Java 8, I have Cat, Food, CurrentState, Outcome domain objects and catService, foodService, outcomeService. So my method looks like this

```
public class Cat {
    private Long ownerId;
    private Long Id;

    public Long getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(Long ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public CurrentState findActiveCurrentState() {
        return new CurrentState();
    }

}

class CurrentState {
    Long outcomeId;

    public Long getOutcomeId() {
        return outcomeId;
    }

    public void setOutcomeId(Long outcomeId) {
        this.outcomeId = outcomeId;
    }

    Outcome findByOutcomeId(Long outcomeId) {
        return new Outcome();
    }
}

class Food {

}

class Outcome {
    Long outcomeId;
    List<String> types;

    public List<String> getTypes() {
        types = new ArrayList<>();
        types.add("Food");
        types.add("Bath");
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }
}


class CatService {
    Optional<Cat> findByOwnerId(Long ownerId) {
        return Optional.of(new Cat());
    }

    public void eatFood(Food food) {

    }
}

class FoodService {
    Food find(Long catId) {
        return new Food();
    }

    class FoodEventService {

        private CatService catService = new CatService();

        private FoodService foodService = new FoodService();

        public void processCatCanEatFoodEvent(Long ownerId) {
            Optional<Cat> cat = catService.findByOwnerId(ownerId);
            if (cat.isPresent()) {
                //dont worry about the findActiveCurrentState(),its not really important
                CurrentState currentState = cat.get().findActiveCurrentState();
                Food food = foodService.find(cat.get().getId());
                Outcome outCome = currentState.findByOutcomeId(currentState.getOutcomeId());

                if (outCome.getTypes().contains("Food")) {
                    catService.eatFood(food);
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

i tried to abstract each of those service calls to a function and then use compose and andThen, but not sure whether it will work or its the right way. So any help would be appreciated, so i am looking to refactor processCatCanEatFoodEvent method. as you asked in the comment updated the class.

Comment: Not having a complete, compilable example to play around with, it’s quite difficult to help you. I might tell you something about `cat.ifPresent(c -> { … }); but I wouldn’t want to to post code that I haven’t compiled first. The risk of errors is too great.

Comment: Updated please see

Comment: Why is `CatService` eating food? Why does `CurrentState` needs its own `outcomeId` passed back to itself by the caller of `findByOutcomeId`? And why do you want to “abstract each of those service calls to a function and then use compose and andThen”? What do you expect from that action?

Comment: Your code looks absolutely fine and there's no point trying to shove Java 8 features where your code is doing fine without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb I’ve learned about `Optional`s is “never use `get()`”. In your case, since you already have the `if` statement, it’s not that hard to find something a bit more elegant:

```
        cat.ifPresent(c -> {
            CurrentState currentState = c.findActiveCurrentState();
            Food food = foodService.find(c.getId());
            Outcome outCome = currentState.findByOutcomeId(currentState.getOutcomeId());

            if (outCome.getTypes().contains("Food")) {
                catService.eatFood(food);
            }
        });
```

For your question, after playing around a bit I tend to agree with Louis Wasserman, there’s no real point in introducing consumers, `compose()` and `andThen()`. If you insist, you may do, for instance:

```
            if (((Function<Outcome, List<String>>) Outcome::getTypes)
                    .andThen(l -> Boolean.valueOf(l.contains("food")))
                    .apply(outCome)) {
                catService.eatFood(food);
            }
```

Not worth the effort, is it?